# Strange unreadable font in ubuntu software center

Tags: fonts

I just finished setting up Ubuntu 14.04. When I open the software center half of the items appear in a font from a language unknown to me like in the scr below. Anyone with a solution for this?

[image: error scr]

Comment: Just use Synaptic or AppGrid. The Ubuntu Software Center is not actively developed anymore and will be replaced in 16.04.